# php script to look for image paths and convert them to base64

Tags: php, base64

I am using a software (adobe animate) that will export an animated .svg file with the images path written on that exported .svg file. Then i need manually to convert them to base64 and manually again replace each `<image xlink:href="">` to the base64 string of the encoded .png image. I was thinking to write a php script that will scan the .svg document for path /img that those images are stored and replace each path in the .svg file with the base64 so at the end one file will contain all the images inline. Any ideas? I am also posting example of a very simple .svg file that contains only one image, it's basically html code.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg id="RECOVER_Untitled-7_2023123103220" image-rendering="auto" baseProfile="basic" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="400" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Scene-1-copy-1" overflow="visible"><g id="Symbol-1" transform="translate(0 86)"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="replace" type="translate" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" keyTimes="0;.04199;.042;.08299;.083;.12499;.125;.16699;.167;.20799;.208;.24999;.25;.29199;.292;.33299;.333;.37499;.375;.41699;.417;.45799;.458;.49999;.5;.54199;.542;.58299;.583;.62499;.625;.66699;.667;.70799;.708;.74999;.75;.79199;.792;.83299;.833;.87499;.875;.91699;.917;.95799;.958;1" values="0,86;0,86;-8.65,90.55;-8.65,90.55;-17.35,95.1;-17.35,95.1;-26.05,99.65;-26.05,99.65;-34.75,104.25;-34.75,104.25;-43.45,108.8;-43.45,108.8;-52.15,113.35;-52.15,113.35;-60.85,117.9;-60.85,117.9;-69.55,122.5;-69.55,122.5;-78.25,127.05;-78.25,127.05;-86.95,131.6;-86.95,131.6;-95.65,136.15;-95.65,136.15;-104.3,140.75;-104.3,140.75;-113,145.3;-113,145.3;-121.7,149.85;-121.7,149.85;-130.4,154.4;-130.4,154.4;-139.1,159;-139.1,159;-147.8,163.55;-147.8,163.55;-156.5,168.1;-156.5,168.1;-165.2,172.65;-165.2,172.65;-173.9,177.25;-173.9,177.25;-182.6,181.8;-182.6,181.8;-191.3,186.35;-191.3,186.35;-200,190.95;-200,190.95" calcMode="discrete"/><image overflow="visible" xlink:href="img/myimage.png" height="128" width="600"/></g></g></svg>`

Comment: “I was thinking to write a php script... Any ideas?” - have you tried anything?

Comment: I was trying and i was very close but i am still learning!The answer from @Adesoji Alu helped so much to understand what i was missing and maybe play with the code to adjust it to my own needs :)